# Expanding solution on a parameter

Tags: equation-solving

How can we expand an iterated value as a set by continuous manipulation of a parameter?

```
a = 1.;
c = 1.42;
ff[c_] = FindRoot[Cosh[c/T]/Cosh[a/T]^2 == 1., {T, 2.5}];
Plot[ff[c], {c, 1.42, 1.6}]
```

Is it possible without `Manipulate`?

Comment: What about this? `ContourPlot[Cosh[c/T]/Cosh[1/T]^2 - 1, {c, 1.42, 1.6}, {T, -3, 3}
 , ContourShading -> None, Contours -> {0}, PlotRange -> All]`. (I don't really think I understand your question. What is meant by "expand an iterated value as a set by continuous manipulation of a parameter"? But based on your code, I *think* what you want is what I've shown.)

Comment: For 5 values of $c = (1.42, 1.57, 0.03) $ with increment $0.03$  we have 5 values of $T$.. When the increment goes to zero, we have a continuous curve of $T$ versus $c$.

Comment: So did you try out the code I posted?

Comment: :)  I did, thank you. if you care to put it up ..shall accept as an answer.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate (using `ContourPlot` to solve for the roots of an implicit, transcendental equation and plotting them), but I have no time to look for one right now.